# Selective listing of files using ls

Tags: unix, grep, ls

I have a set of files in a directory named 
 
abc
data.txt
hello
hello1
hello1.text
hello.txt

I want to list only the files hello and hello1.

I tried using this command  `ls -lrt hello* | ls -lrt !(hello*.*)`

The output which I got is 
abc
data.txt
hello
hello1

The pipe function is not working in this scenario.

Please help me with this issue

Comment: If these are the **only** files you want, why not call it explicitly? `ls -lrt hello  hello1`. Do you really need a pattern?

Comment: I just gave an example here. If I need a multiple files without extension, explicit calling won't be helpful I feel

Comment: I see, then you should revise your example a little (maybe add hello2 which will also apply) or you could phrase the general case you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you tagged with grep, give this a try:

```
ls -l |grep 'hello1\?$'
```

if the digit could be dynamic, try this

```
ls -l|grep 'hello[0-9]*$'
```

Comment: This is perfectly working for me . Is it possible to try the same function without using grep ?

Comment: @SethuramanSrinivasan you seem to be extremely confused. First in your question you try piping the output of `ls` to a second `ls` and then you now ask if you can do a `grep` without using `grep`. I recommend you get the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson or some intro to UNIX book and read at least the first couple of chapters.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right:

```
ls hello*
```

or

```
ls -l hello*
```

Comment: This will also list `hello1.text` & `hello.txt` which weren't requested by the op.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash extended [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls hello*([^.])
hello  hello1
```

That pattern is "hello" followed by zero or more non-dot characters.

Comment: My money's on because you aren't using bash. Are you using bash?